# Created app not accessible via http://localhost:1841/MyApp

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, senchatouch-2.4

I'm using Mac and **Sencha touch 2.4** along with **sencha cmd 6**. I'm able to create the app named MyApp as per the instructions given in the site with slight modifications (added a '.' in the end to tell the cmd to create the MyApp in the current folder). The structure is created properly.

The issue is, as per the instructions given in the website, if I try to access the generated app thru browser by typing http://localhost:1841/MyApp its says page not found. I think I'm making some rudimentary error here.

Answer (score 2):

That url is active when you run the command

```
sencha app watch
```

From the project directory.

Once the command starts in your terminal you will see some output logging. Just leave that open while you want to be able to access the app from localhost with the port you are given. If you want to quit the sencha app watch command press `control + c`

Comment: This is exactly what I just wanted to post. More info can be found here: https://www.sencha.com/blog/optimizing-the-development-process-with-sencha-cmd-5/